# How do I troubleshoot CSS not rendering in ASP.NET validation controls?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a couple of ASP.NET Validation Controls, namely RequiredFieldValidator and CustomValidator which I applied a CSS style to using the CssClass property, but it doesn't render properly in any browser.  I'm trying to add spacing around it using margin/padding, but that isn't being applied.  Color and font however is being applied.  Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding here?  Or does anyone know where/how I can start troubleshooting?  I've looked at various posts on the web but can't seem to find a solution to my problem.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too broad really for Stack Overflow, but start by using Developer Tools in your browser of choice, inspect your validation messages etc and see what styles are being applied and what is over-writing them

Comment: Use your browser's Web Inspector (F12) tools. They all have a style inspector area which shows you what styles are being applied and why some rules are overriding others.

Comment: Thanks.  I already have done that (F12/CTRL-SHIFT-I), and it shows which style is being used, but it doesn't tell me why the margin is not being applied.  Or give me any kind of hint that there is some kind of inheritance issue, etc.